# Determine all local extreme values and saddle points for $f(x,y)$ :

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Determine all local extreme values and saddle points for $f(x,y)$ : $\sin x + \cos y + \cos(x-y)$.

I calculated partial derivatives :

$$f_x = \cos x - \sin(x-y)$$

$$f_y = -\sin y + \sin(x-y)$$

and would normally equate it to $0$. Do I have to do that and use some trigonometric identities? Is there another way?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Use that $$\cos(x)-\sin(y)=2 \sin \left(-\frac{x}{2}-\frac{y}{2}+\frac{\pi
   }{4}\right) \sin
   \left(\frac{x}{2}-\frac{y}{2}+\frac{\pi
   }{4}\right)$$ and $$\sin(x)-\sin(y)=2 \sin \left(\frac{x}{2}-\frac{y}{2}\right) \cos
   \left(\frac{x}{2}+\frac{y}{2}\right)$$

Comment: Is there a page with identities like that?

Comment: I don't no sorry, i would search for " Trigonometric Identities"